# What to do about 13.04 questions?

Tags: discussion

What do we do about 13.04 questions? Flag them as off topic?

As far as I know, questions about non-released versions of Ubuntu is not supported?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Towards the end of a development cycle we tend to chill out a bit on the closures.

Things should be set in stone by this point (Beta 2) so questions and answers are a lot less theoretical than the "WILL UNITY v92 HAVE MORE CAAOBELLz?" that we get on the first day of the cycle.

**In short:** unless it's a really awful question in itself (including bug reports) it's probably okay to accept it.

Comment: Alright. So I shouldn't flag them, when I see them? Except, of course, if they're horrible? ( I haven't been with AskUbuntu long enough to know the 'usual' procedure of new cycles.)

Comment: Sounds about right and don't worry about 'usual procedure'... We make it up as we go along.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I'll probably figure it out, as I stay here longer.

Answer (score 6):

As [Oli says](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6463/22949), if they're otherwise good questions, at this point we can allow them.

However, keep in mind that, especially near the end of the beta when many people are installing it for the first time, **many 13.04 questions posted recently are bug reports.**

So every time you see a 13.04 question (especially in a close or reopen review queue), ask yourself if it's really a bug report. Many of these questions are outright crashes, or ask about strange behavior just after a crash. Some bug questions are more subtle; generally, a question that asks about strange behavior that's *definitely wrong* and *unlikely to be a result of wrong configuration* should be considered a bug report and closed (with helpful comments to explain to the OP what to do).